# Converting webpages to mobile app using cordova

Tags: javascript, php, json, cordova, endpoint

I've been trying to be able to make android and iOS apps using the same knowledge I have in Js and PHP. Using Cordova, I'm able to do it. But when it comes to converting any database driven app, it can't fetch the data from MySQL database.

I know that Cordova can't communicate with MySQL directly by interpreting PHP scripts. I have to create an API that read the data and that API will be saved on the server in JSON format. I was able to do it.

I have then to allow a main J's file for my app to locate where the JSON file is located but it returns nothing.

Here's the API.

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "yourdbname";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

The main JS file is:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    fetchData();
}
function fetchData() {
    var url = 'http://localhost/yourproject/api.php';
    cordova.plugin.http.sendRequest(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {},
        timeout: 5000
    }, function (response) {
        displayData(JSON.parse(response.data));
    }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
function displayData(data) {
    var tableBody = document.querySelector('#studentTable tbody');
    data.forEach(function (student) {
        var row = tableBody.insertRow();
        var idCell = row.insertCell(0);
        var nameCell = row.insertCell(1);
        var ageCell = row.insertCell(2);
        idCell.innerHTML = student.id;
        nameCell.innerHTML = student.name;
        ageCell.innerHTML = student.age;
    });
}
```

Unfortunately the html return empty cells and developer tools in browser show no sign of reaching the API.

If you know what to do, please tell me.

Comment: So what happens when you run the code which tries to send the request to the API? Any errors in the console? Does it show the request being sent at all? What is the response status code, if so?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `function makeRequest() {
    try { const response = await fetch('http://localhost/yourproject/');
  console.log('response.status: ', response.status); // ️ 200
  console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }   makeRequest();
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
 fetchData();
} ` The console says: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/yourproject/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

Comment: it seems that this part of the index.js is not being executed since console shows nothing : `function fetchData() {
    var url = 'http://localhost/yourproject/api.php';

    cordova.plugin.http.sendRequest(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {},
        timeout: 5000
    }, function (response) {
        displayData(JSON.parse(response.data));
    }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
` or the mistake is related to the http cordova plugin

Comment: "show no sign of reaching the API." add a console.log before cordova.plugin.http.sendRequest to make sure fetchData is being executed.